# AWS Tasks of Rails Docker container keep exiting, server gives 503 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, amazon-ec2

I deployed a container to AWS ECS, after booting Puma everything is okay for a while. After some time, all tasks are ended and when trying to hit the page you see a `503 Service Temporarily Unavailable` error. There's nothing in the logs though, so it seems to be not related to Rails. Is there anything else I can do to get to the cause of this issue? I'm kind of new to this type of hosting, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: If there aren't any containers running then I think 503 is the response the elastic load balancer will give. Not sure why the containers are being killed, but you say "tasks" which in ECS are one-off runs with a limited lifetime. You might want to use an ECS "service" instead.

Comment: I think it was the load balancer kiiling the individual tasks because the healthcheck was failing.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running your rails application as an ECS service. Do check your ECS Service Events. You will get to know the exact issue over there.

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service-event-messages.html

If there is no clue over there then navigate to the "STOPPED" task and you will see why container exited.

Click on the name of your cluster -> Tasks Tab -> Click on task id -> Click on containers arrow, There you will be able to see why your containers stops.